# How to fix php.DEBUG: fsockopen() :Connection refused?

Tags: php, symfony, fsockopen

I want to use server of symfony,to close my apache2 at first.

```
service apache2 stop
```

My command history in symfony:

```
symfony new myblog lts
cd /home/debian8/myblog
php app/console server:run  -vvv
[2016-03-19 15:14:11] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) {"type":2,"file":"/home/debian8/myblog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":59,"level":28928}


 [OK] Server running on http://127.0.0.1:8000


 // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
  RUN  '/usr/bin/php5' '-S' '127.0.0.1:8000' '/home/debian8/myblog/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php'
  ERR  [Sat Mar 19 15:14:36 2016] 127.0.0.1:36496 [200]: /
  ERR  [Sat Mar 19 15:14:37 2016] 127.0.0.1:36497 [200]: /_wdt/cf9a53
  ERR  [Sat Mar 19 15:14:37 2016] 127.0.0.1:36498 [200]: /favicon.ico
  ERR  [Sat Mar 19 15:14:37 2016] 127.0.0.1:36499 [200]: /favicon.ico
  ERR
```

Some material say it is the fact that port 8000 don't listen on result in the problem.
How to set the builtin dev server in symfony properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you look on how the `fsockopen` is used in server command (latest), you will see that it's [used to make sure that nothing is listening on the port](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/0c1b9bacd871d4e623ad64a2bbff1e4bc1d62334/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerStartCommand.php#L173). It uses silence operator, but it still may be possible the raise warning if your php setup uses [`scream`](http://php.net/manual/en/scream.examples-simple.php) to override it.

The warning says - "there is nothing there" which is what's supposed to happen. Only the warning should not be raised due to the `@` silence operator.